# NGRX execution order of dispatch and select

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a post button which will trigger the addPost() method to dispatch action (Add post into server) and then select the added post Id. I have a Add_Success reducer to assign the added post id into selectedPostId which will be used by the getCurrentPostHeaderId selector.

The correct execution order that I'm expecting is:
1. Dispatch AddPost Action
2. Select the added post Id

But the order always went wrong after the first execution:
1. Select the previous post Id
2. Dispatch AddPost Action
3. Select the added post Id

On the first run, the execution is correct, the action was dispatched and correct added id was displayed in the log. 
[image]

But if i immediately add another post after the first run, it seems the old selector will be executed first and the previous id will be displayed. After this, only the new post will be added successfully and new post id is selected.
[image]

My Component:

```
addPost() {
const postStatus = Object.assign({}, this.newPostForm.value);
let postHeader: any = {};

postHeader.postStatus = postStatus;

this.store.dispatch(new postHeaderActions.AddToPost(postHeader)); //Add post

this.store.select(
  fromPost.getCurrentPostHeaderId
)
.subscribe((post) => {
  if (post) {
      console.log(post); //Return the new added post id
  }
});
}
```

My Reducer & Selector:

```
case ActionTypes.Add_Success: {
        console.log('hey');
        return postHeaderAdapter.addOne(action.payload, {
            ...state,
            selectedPostId: action.payload.id,
            loaded: true
        });
    }

export const getCurrentPostHeaderId = createSelector(
    getPostHeaderFeatureState,
    (state: PostHeaderState) => state.selectedPostId
);
```

The same goes on for multiple run, you can see that from second run onward, it will return the previous Id before showing the new Id. 
[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no other reducer than can change `selectedPostId` ?

Comment: There are no other reducer changing selectedPostId

Answer (score 0):

One way to listen only the next id is to listen only when the id has changed:

```
this.store.select(
  fromPost.getCurrentPostHeaderId
)
   .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working, still showing previous Id